# OpenVAS create alert with HTML attachment

Tags: xml, openvas

I am having difficulty creating an alert with an attachment "HTML" (“Method > Email > Content > Attach > Html")

I have the ID for the HTML report, but can't figure out how to insert that into the ""

```
<create_alert>
<name>test3</name>
<condition>Always</condition>
<event>Task run status changed<data>Done<name>status</name></data></event>
<method>Email<data>test@example.com<name>to_address</name></data>
<data>support@example.com<name>from_address</name></data></method>
</create_alert>
```

I tried adding in "6c248850-1f62-11e1-b082-406186ea4fc5notice_attach_format" to the method section, but this didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create an alert with a PDF attachment like this, so you only need to subsitute
c402cc3e-b531-11e1-9163-406186ea4fc5 with uuid of HTML :

```
omp -u username -w password --xml="<create_alert><name>AlertName</name><condition>Always</condition><event>Task run status changed<data>Done<name>status</name></data></event><method>Email<data>2<name>notice</name></data><data>example@email.com<name>from_address</name></data><data>c402cc3e-b531-11e1-9163-406186ea4fc5<name>notice_attach_format</name></data><data>example@gmail.com<name>to_address</name></data></method></create_alert>"
```